# Работа с файлами в python, записать общее содержимое

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть два файла: файл1.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

файл2.txt:

```
2 4 6
```

нужно создать файл3.txt, который перепишет все с файл1.txt, но изменит цифры, которые есть в файл2.txt. Hу, например, должно выйти - файл3.txt:

```
1 (2) 3 (4) 5 (6)
```

Код примерно такой, но здесь в переменную `text` записывается лишь последняя замена.

```
f_1_read = open('file_1.txt')
f_1 = f_1_read.read()

f_2_read = open('file_2.txt')
f_2 = f_2_read.read().split()

f_1_read.close()
f_2_read.close()

f = open('file_3.html', 'a')
f.write('<html>\n<p>')
for i in f_2:
        text = f_1.replace(i, '<i>' + i + '</i>')
f.write(text)
f.write('</p>\n</html>')
f.close()
```